# get property value of an array using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
arr = [{"fname","Amy","lname":"Johnson"}]
```

I know by using $.each I do retrieve Amy and Johnson like this

```
$.each(arr, function(){
console.log(this.fname) //Amy
});
```

but I want to match Amy with my DOM, how can I retrieve the property `"fname"` value?

Comment: You have a syntax error in `arr`: `[{"fname" >> , <<"Amy","lname":"Johnson"}]` - that comma should be a `:`. Otherwise [it works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/d1yzrj18/)

Comment: `[{"fname","Amy","lname":"Johnson"}]` or `[{"fname":"Amy","lname":"Johnson"}]`

Answer (score 1):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/htt9p1b8/)

Check your array format is wrong

```
arr = [{"fname":"Amy","lname":"Johnson"}];
```

youre using `,` instead of `:`

Use this

```
arr = [{"fname":"Amy","lname":"Johnson"}];

$.each(arr, function(){
console.log(this.fname + this.lname) //Amy
});
```

Comment: The *array* format is fine, the format of the *object* within that array is wrong.

Comment: he can get the result of `Amy Jackson`

Comment: Your answer is correct, just pointing out an issue with the terminology that's all.

Comment: Oh ok @RGraham i dont know what u are coming to say please edit my answer

Comment: I want to get fname and lname not the result of it. duh.

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be like this :

```
arr = [{"fname" : "Amy","lname":"Johnson"}]
```

and you can iterate it like this :

```
$.each(arr, function(index, item ) {
        console.log(item.fname);
        console.log(item.lname);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You `arr` should be a vaild array of objects

`arr = [{"fname":"Amy","lname":"Johnson"}]`

Then you can do

```
$.each(arr, function(){
console.log(this.fname) //Amy
});
```

**Edited:**

To get Amy just do `var fname = arr[0]["fname"]` or `var fname = arr[0].fname`

To get fname, lname you need to use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Do it like `console.log(Object.keys(arr[0]));`

It will print an array `["fname", "lname"]`

Comment: I don't want to get Amy, I want fname.